# Android view .setTranslationY() view cropped

Tags: android, layout

i'm searching for hours, but don't find a solution. I have a Layout as the following:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/remote_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TevidiHome$RemoteFragment" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/remote_extra"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".TevidiHome$FragmentRemote" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/remote_text_active"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/remote_text_waiting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/remote_text_active"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/remote_text_store"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-500dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/remote_text_waiting"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionNone"
            android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/remote_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/remote_text_active"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remote_logo_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/number_block" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/remote_border"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/remote_logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remote_border_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/remote_border" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/remote_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/remote_extra"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tevidi_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remote_tevidi_logo_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/tevidi_logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/remote_sos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
                android:contentDescription="@string/remote_sos_desc"
                android:src="@drawable/sos_off" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/remote_alarm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
                android:contentDescription="@string/remote_alarm_desc"
                android:src="@drawable/alarm_off" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Arrows -->

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/remote_top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lenter code hereayout_above="@+id/remote_ok"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remote_top_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/remote_top" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/remote_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/remote_ok"
            android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remote_left_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/remote_left" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/remote_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remote_ok_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/remote_ok" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/remote_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/remote_ok"
            android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remote_right_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/remote_right" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/remote_down"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/remote_ok"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remote_down_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/remote_down" />

        <!-- Bottom Buttons -->

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/remote_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remote_back_desc"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/remote_back" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/remote_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remote_menu_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/remote_menu" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The remote_extra Layout is drawn out of the screen by View.setTranslationY(-170) and by a fling gesture it can be swipped down. That works great. 
The problem is: Because of the TranslationY the remote_main Layout is not at the bottom of the screen but 170pixels above. I don't manage to bring it back to the bottom. When i programmatically make the remote_main layout higher, the buttons are cut off.

can't add screenshots. Therefore one is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/52erx4jatzsqz80/Screenshot_2013-11-22-13-46-17.png

And it should be like here. The empty space at the bottom should be filled with the views above: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xw8km88lmz9be4q/Screenshot_good.png

I tried the following nothing helps:

```
LayoutParams params = rootView.findViewById(R.id.remote_parent).getLayoutParams();
                rootView.findViewById(R.id.remote_parent).setTranslationY(UP_PADDING);

LayoutParams params2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.remote_main).getLayoutParams();
params2.height = 1400;

((ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.remote_parent)).setClipChildren(false);
((ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.remote_main)).setClipChildren(false);
rootView.requestLayout();
rootView.invalidate();
```

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: pls post some screen shots

Comment: have added a screenshot

Comment: It may help to provide a drawing of what you want the screen to look like, so it is more clear.

Comment: I added a screenshot how it should look like. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i managed to move to buttons, but then they were no more clickable ;-(

So i switched to SlidingDrawer. After a while I found out, that it is deprecated, but anyway it's exactly what I need...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem - translated view was higher than screen (wrap_content had more pixels than screen in Y dimension)and when I translated view up, bottom part was not rendered at all.

My solution: use ScrollView as slinged view, but if it reaches top of the screen, call `scrollTo()` instead of `translateY()`

```
private void customScroll(int y)
{
    setTranslationY(Math.max(y, 0));
    scrollTo(0,Math.max(0, -y));
}
```